# Atribuir valor null para um campo

Tags: mysql

Eu estava fazendo alguns testes no banco de dados local, e para eles acabei por modificar um campo que estava `null`, atribuindo um valor a ele.

Agora que já fiz os testes, quero atribuir novamente o valor `null` para aquele campo. Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acredito que um simples update resolva o problema

```
UPDATE TABELA SET CAMPO = NULL
```

Answer (score -4):

Lembrando que é preciso usar um begin tran antes para caso de algum problema, depois conseguir voltar com um rollback.
E também é preciso colocar where com as condições, para chegar na linha desejada, para não fazer update em tudo.